# How to query data like only for point by from a grouplayer by using WMSGetFeatureInfo in Openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, filter, getfeatureinfo

till now I have been known how to query data from a groupLayer by using WMSGetFeatureInfo while the point is it shows a lot of  associate results features,so I aim to query a single layer infomation from `enter code here`a groupLayer,just like only query point information.I don't konw whether it is right to use filter or CQL ,does anybody know how to handle this and can anybody give me a demo?

```
Here is My code:
var styleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
             "default": {
                 fillColor: "#990033",
                 fillOpacity: 0.4, 
                 strokeColor: "#990033",
                 strokeWidth: 1,
                 strokeDashstyle: "dash"

             }
         });

        var highlightLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Highlighted Features", {
            displayInLayerSwitcher: false, 
            isBaseLayer: false, 
            styleMap:styleMap
            });
        this.map.addLayer(highlightLayer);

        var filterCql1 = "ROADCODE IS NOT NULL";
        var filterCql2 = "ROADNAME IS NOT NULL";
        var filterCql3 = "STARTZH > 0";
        var info = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
            url : 'http://geoserver:8080/hdmapserver/wms',
            title : 'Identify features by clicking',
            //output:"object",

            /*
             * hover:true, handlerOptions:{ //"click": {delay: 100}, "hover":
             * {delay: 300} },
             */
        //  layers:[point,point1],
            maxFeatures : 10,

            infoFormat : "application/vnd.ogc.gml",
            vendorParams : {
                //'CQL_FILTER' : filterCql1/* +";"+filterCql2+";"+filterCql3, */,
                //featureId:"",
                radius : 5
            },
            queryVisible : false,
            eventListeners : {
                getfeatureinfo : function(event) {
                    var data = event.features[0].attributes;
                    if(event.text != null){
                        this.map.addPopup(new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                                "chicken",
                                this.map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy),
                                null,
                                "<div>"+data.num+"</div>"+"<div>":"+data.name+"</div>", 
                                null, 
                                true));     
                    }
                    //console.log(data);    

                    if(event.features.length>=1){
                        for(var i=0,j=event.features.length; i<j;i++){
                            console.log(event.features[i].geometry);    
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your control just set QUERYLAYERS: [point] (or whichever layer you want to query) and only results for that layer will be returned.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but still have a problem.At first,I have add a group layer on map,as you said,I must add another layer like a single point layer on map,then set QUERYLAYERS:[point]?